# Fixing infos error in Flutter project with a command

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter project with some Infos(less than warnings) in my console in vsCode.

Like : `remove unused imports` ..

I got a ton of them after months of work. Is there a way to fix them all with a simple command or any tool ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

> dart fix --apply

The dart fix command finds and fixes two types of issues:

Analysis issues identified by dart analyze that have associated automated fixes (sometimes called quick-fixes or code actions)

Outdated API usages when updating to newer releases of the Dart and Flutter SDKs.

See this doc:
https://dart.dev/tools/dart-fix